# Library Structuring using require

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am not sure what to call this question so any revise is welcomed!!! I am trying to learn to keep a clean js library structure of third party scripts as well as my own. I have no knowledge other than the basic method of adding js files to my page other than the old way..

I found this on searching and it makes some sense to me seeing that I am not real good with javascript or jquery https://github.com/volojs/create-template

my question is I have a folder structure as follows

- index.html
- assets/js/lib/gsap/
- assets/js/lib/bootstrap/
- assets/js/lib/whateverelse

in my index.html file i have my link to jquery and to the file called app.js

but I am confused on how to get this to work how to i call the files from the directory?

Basicly I want to call multi js files from 1 file

Comment: `<script src="./assets/js/ib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>`

Comment: yes I understand how to add the script using a link I am asking how to call all of them from 1 js file not 9 different requests

Comment: I think you can't do that with js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly u need files included from app.js and app.js included in index.html.

**app.js**

```
function dynamicallyLoadScript(url) {
var script = document.createElement("script"); // Make a script DOM node
script.src = url; // Set it's src to the provided URL

document.head.appendChild(script); // Add it to the end of the head section of the page (could change 'head' to 'body' to add it to the end of the body section instead)
}
dynamicallyLoadScript('assets/js/lib/bootstrap/test.js');
dynamicallyLoadScript('assets/js/lib/gsap/test.js');
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

function taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file). Guy answers almost all the related questions.